# Github Desktop keeps .gitignore files when switching branches

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I don't know if this is a bug or intended, but with Github Desktop the files specified on `.gitignore` are carried over to any other branch I switch to and it asks me to commit those files. One fix is to have the same `.gitignore` file on all other branches, but that will clutter up the environment.

Eg:

- **Branch 1** has `node_modules` in `.gitignore`.
- Switching to **Branch 2**, `node_modules` is carried over and asks to be committed.

Comment: What do you mean by "clutter"? If you want something ignored, put it in `.gitignore`. Otherwise that thing you want ignored will "clutter" your work.

Comment: I have two completely different versions of the app with different modules. Since the modules are ignored they carry over, but yea I realised that this isn't the way to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally want to have the same `.gitignore` file in all branches.  If you want to ignore `node_modules` in a particular branch, you probably don't want to check it in while on other branches.

Since Git only honors the `.gitignore` file in the working tree and not the ones in other branches, you're seeing that branch 2, which is missing it, has your `node_modules` directory not ignored.  As a result, they show as untracked files, and GitHub Desktop suggests that they be committed.

Comment: oh ok, makes sense. Thank you.